# Problem with fetching helm chart from kubernetes-charts

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I have a deployment script that is fetching rabbitmq from `kubernetes-charts` reports

```
- name: rabbitmq
  version: 0.6.17
  repository: https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com/
```

It seems like this is not working from yesterday. Does someone which repository url I can use instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official chart repository is deprecated. For the specific Helm chart, you should check https://artifacthub.io/.

In the case of `rabbitmq`, you can find it [here](https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/bitnami/rabbitmq). And here are the Helm commands.

```
$ helm repo add bitnami https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami
$ helm install my-release bitnami/rabbitmq
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It seems like bitnami repo doesn't contain the old version of rabbitmq that is being used, so I added the `helm repo add stable https://charts.helm.sh/stable` version which I found online.